# PulseEffects doesn't run

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I use UbuntuStudio 18.04.1 LTS inside 4 computers.

Since last Ubuntu standard updating (security, mostly), in one of my desktop computers PulseEffects doesn't run anymore. This very good program runs without problems in all the other 3 computers.

I try to run the program with the line command option and I get this message:

> Assertion 'o' failed at pulse/operation.c:133, function
>   pa_operation_get_state().
>
> Aborting.
>
> Abortado (`core' generado)

The only one difference between this desktop computer and the other 3, is about this installation has been upgrading since Lubuntu 15.x. The others have been installed from UbuntuStudio 18.04.1 LTS LiveCD.

What is wrong here?

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried the command `dconf reset -f /com/github/wwmm/pulseeffects/`

Comment: I used your idea and... Nothing! I uninstalled the whole program and, then, I installed it, again, and... Nothing! This program runs so fine in the other 3 computers, but not in this one. I don't understand why!

Comment: Does somebody know what does "pulse/operation.c:133, function pa_operation_get_state()" mean? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me by now

```
sudo apt remove --purge pulseeffects
```

then remove from "Software" application (i don't know why i could still find it there after purging); then reboot and re-install from "Software"

Comment: I did it, but... NOTHING! BTW: I don't have the option "PulseEffects" in my "Software Center" app. Apparently, my Software Center is different of yours, I don't know why...

Comment: maybe because i actually use [Flathub] (https://flathub.org/home) on my Software Center